# HTML element type change on onclick and onfocus not working in IE Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

i am using below codes for changing the type of HTML element during onclick and onfocus.

```
function ChangeToPassField() {

   document.getElementById('password').type="password";
   document.getElementById('password').focus();
```

}

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" onblur="ChangeToTextField(); if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" onclick="ChangeToPassField(); if (this.value == 'Password') { this.value = ''; } else { this.value; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') { this.value=''; }; this.type='password';" value="Password" style="width:230px; height:25px; margin-left:5px; background:none; border:0px;" />
```

the event onclick and onfocus not working IE7 and IE8.it displays the error like

"Could not get the type property: This command is not supported"

How can i Solve this?

Comment: Don't abuse the value attribute as a fake `<label>`, it introduces accessibility problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` attribute [cannot be changed in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534700.aspx) (see the "Remarks" section). You could get around this by replacing the `input` element with a new one.

Comment: @Matt- Thanks for the link, I was just about to add it in too!